# how to check compare variable in LINQ where condition

Tags: c#, linq

i'm getting some value inside a variable and i want to compare it inside my LINQ query. i tried following,

```
string var_name = Convert.ToString(res[2]);

var result = from p in listData
             where p.cd == var_name
             select p;
```

but getting error `Embedded statement can not be a declaration or labeled statement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that this is connected to LINQ?

Error `Embedded statement can not be a declaration or labeled statement` usually means that you are doing something like this:

```
//WRONG:
if (true)
    int i=5;
i++;
```

In that case you have to change it to:

```
//CORRECT
if (true)
{
    int i=5;
    i++;
}
```